# Why did Daenerys drop her ring?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In the episode of Game of Thrones "Mother's Mercy" (S5 E10) when

> Daenerys is surrounded by a Khalasar,

she drops a ring into the dirt.

Do we know the significance of this ring? Is it meaningful that she dropped that particular piece of jewelry into the dirt?

Comment: I was *just* coming to ask that.

Comment: @TheHonorableNedStark - Didn't you get your head chopped off like 4 seasons back? :P

Comment: @Stark07: Now I'm like a dead teammate in Counter-Strike.

Comment: :D Except your head is literally floating above the entire map I suppose... -_-

Comment: @HC_ IMHO dropping a ring is hardly something that requires spoiler protection.

Comment: @MattMcNabb, I think the point was that the unedited title proved Dany made it to the last episode alive, hence spoiling any uncertainty while watching the fifth season (I think that's what HC was saying)

Comment: @MacCooper Does not the fact that a season 5 exist spoil any uncertainty of watching seasons 1-4?

Comment: @TLP haha no I mean he's now know Dany doesn't die in S5 E9 or E8 or E7 etc etc. I don't personally care, mind you, that's just what I think he meant :P

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's explained in [Game of Thrones Season 5: Inside the Episode #10](https://www.google.ge/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QqQIwAGoVChMIw4jevuKRxgIVZZVyCh3HXADA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DxHMuqH7yOQc&ei=VM5-VcOOGeWqygPHuYGADA&usg=AFQjCNEcRET6BlYkdyQ0YJ0L5pklg0HGkg&sig2=udER6GXin_tW6atEw-juqw&bvm=bv.95515949,d.bGQ).

Start watching from 4:50 to get your answer.

In short:

> The ring is "bread crumb" to point the direction that she's been taken.

Comment: Seriously? She expects her companions to find her based on a ring she drops in the middle of a huge grass plain? That's D&D's idea behind this scene?

Comment: @BCdotWEB Well, like it or not, that's official.

Comment: That was my first guess, but then I had the same reaction as @BCdotWEB here.

Comment: @BCdotWEB  "Not idly do the leaves of Lórien fall"

Comment: Cannot argue with with that source. So with regards to the significance or the ring, at this time we can't assume anything about it? It is *just* jewelry as far as we are aware?

Comment: @chriszumberge seems so

Comment: A breadcrumb? HAAAAHAHAAAA.....

Comment: Yeah I dunno about leaving the ring as a breadcrumb. That field is awfully big. I just figured she wanted to get rid of any evidence that she is something other than a girl living free with a dragon - however she'd like to spin it. Maybe she'll try and act Dorthraki or something. Probably just didn't want them to be like, "what's up with the ring, girl? You from Meereen? I used to make my living selling slaves to them, but now I had to sell my other horse.  All because of that goddam white-haired queen of theirs.  Saaaaaay...."

Comment: I mean, how useful is a ring as a breadcrumb when there was already a thousand horses tramping through the grass, circling around a central point for no discernible reason, then heading off in a common direction together. THAT is your breadcrumb, even I could follow that trail.

Comment: @MishaRosnach if you were to live in a world with just 3 live dragons, and you were forced to hide your identity... yes, get rid of the ring, then the Dothraki will think "this is not the *lady with Dragons* we are looking for"

Comment: Well yeah I guess she probably would have to keep the dragon on the down low too. Hopefully he understands the politics of the region enough not to visit for a bit :)

Comment: @MishaRosnach I agree that the breadcrumb theory doesn't totally make sense, and I'll admit that I *like* the theory that she's hiding her identity/trying to cover up the fact she remarried the most.. but it's hard to argue when a writer/producer literally uses the word "breadcrumb" when referring to the scene, and every other answer (so far) is based on speculation.

Comment: JBear: "Looks like a massive khalasar has been here, swirling around a central point. Probably nothing."   Daario: [walking over to centre] "Look , a ring!"   JBear: "Khaleesi's ring"    Daario+JBear: [eyes meet]

Comment: @AndrewCoonce It's not to give a direction, it's just to say that she was there. Then they can follow the trail of 1,000 horses, which as you say will not be difficult. But without the ring, Jorah and Daario have no way to positively connect Dany with the khalasar that passed through the area.

Comment: Regardless of how realistic tracking Dany will be using the ring as a breadcrumb, it's still a [pretty well used trope](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TrailOfBreadCrumbs). Especially in Fantasy.

Comment: Maybe there is a non-ludicrous explanation. Wasn't one of the skills Daario asked Tyrion about "tracking animals across a wilderness" and/or "hunting with animals" or similar? Dragons probably leave plenty of large charred skeletal clues a hunter could use to find the right general area... Then assuming the hunting party took hounds trained on her scent,  they could find the ring the ring by scent and deduce what happened  and which way they went by the khalasar's trail

Comment: All these people criticizing the breadcrumb theory have clearly never read/watched Lord of the Rings (or any one of a dozen other stories that have used this plot device.)

Comment: S6E01 confirms it acted as a breadcrumb

Comment: Assuming someone finds it (big assumption), it's VERY useful as a breadcrumb.  A trampled field says the Dothraki were there.  There would be no indication that Daenerys was there or that they took her.

Answer (score 9):

Why the tv-script writers thought she should drop her ring, who knows. It does sound like [Nika's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/92625/2256) is the official story. I would like to add some things, and a few thoughts.

It does seem like this is an homage to Lord of the Rings, when Merry and Pippin are abducted by orcs, and leave a piece of jewellery behind as a way to signal their friends. GRRM is fond of homages, and [his books are full of them.](http://asoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/topic/784-references-and-homages/)

*Not idly do the leaves of Lorien fall.* If this is the case, it is rather weak, in my opinion. Aragorn and Legolas had extraordinary abilities, and followed a given track. This was in the middle of nowhere. If she expects anyone to find it, she is optimistic on the verge of delusional. If this is an actual plot line that is going to happen, it is rather far fetched.

Another explanation might be that she would get rid of evidence of her new marriage to Hizdahr, or her old marriage to Khal Drogo. However, seeing as she was discovered because she was flying a dragon, the chance of any such ruse to work would be microscopic indeed. "Say, perhaps she is some *other* girl riding a dragon." No.

However... SPOILER Season 6, and/or ADWD/TWOW -- Mystery spoiler, be warned!

> as the script writers are not unaware, this is when [Mirri Maaz Duur's](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Mirri_Maz_Duur) prophecy starts to come true:
>
> *"When the sun rises in the west and sets in the east," said Mirri Maz Duur. "When the seas go dry and mountains blow in the wind like leaves. When your womb quickens again, and you bear a living child. Then he [Drogo] will return, and not before."*
>
> As described [here](http://www.westeros.org/Citadel/Prophecies/Entry/1799), the following things have happened in the books:
>
> - Dorne has "risen" in Westeros, and Quentyn died in Mereen, "The Suns Son"
> - The Dothraki sea -- the vast grasslands around Mereen -- have gone dry with the coming winter
> - Rhaegal and Viserion broke free and destroyed pyramids (mountains) in Mereen 
> - Daenerys' womb quickened when she had her "moon blood" (menstruation)

Comment: I wouldn't exactly say it was in the middle of nowhere, her dragon took her to what appears to be one of his nests. And IIRC, Daario eludes to the fact that he and Jorah are both capable trackers. Though, if this really is the proper answer, it probably would have been a bit wiser of her to tear off strips of her dress instead. But it could be, as you said, a homage to LotR.

Answer (score 3):

*Not idly do the leaves of Lorien fall*

she was leaving something for jorah and daario to track.

Answer (score 2):

No... she dropped the ring because this is the original army she was with when she was married to drogo... and according to their tradition... she couldn't get married again. hence why she dropped the ring

Comment: Within the context of the show, it seems that we've seen no evidence that the ring she dropped was symbolic of her marriage to Hizdahr zo Loraq, nor was it revealed that the Khalasar approaching had any association with Khal Drogo. All we have to go on is the (reliable) source @NikaG. referenced.

Comment: @chriszumberge I figured it was related to Drogo somehow, and if the leader of the Khalasar that found her (regardless of who lead it) noticed it on her it would have marked her as a potential enemy (i.e. rival queen that could bear an enemy) and she'd just be killed outright instead of taken captive. Official or not, I like that theory better than "find a ring among the Dothraki sea" :P

Comment: @NickT trust me.. I like every answer better than "finding a ring among the Dothraki sea" :)

Answer (score 2):

So who was this army that immediately surrounded our new favorite dynamic duo? If the books are any indication, they are none other than a khalasar Dothraki army, led by Khal Jhaqo, who was a former lieutenant of Drogo’s before his untimely death. So, naturally, this is bound to make things a little awkward for all parties involved, given that a Khaleesi is traditionally supposed to live with the crones of the Dosh Khaleen shortly after her Khal dies. Since Dany failed to do so, they may be a little curious (and more than a little upset) if they catch wind of what she’s been up to instead. Like the fact that she got married again to a nobleman of Meereen, Hizdahr zo Loraq. Hence why she dropped her ring out of sight as the army approached her.

Comment: Great answer, and welcome to the site!

Comment: Do you have any citation that the ring indicates a betrothal or even her status as a ruler? Otherwise there would not be any reason to drop it for this reason.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it was an "engagement ring" given by Hizdahr and she didn't want the Khalasar to see see that she had taken another husband and not followed the custom of becoming a dosh khaleen. I'm not sure, but by just looking at her face it looks like she was trying to hide it inconspicuously rather than leave a "breadcrumb" (and seriously, who did she expect to find that ring? Someone that just happened to be combing the entire Dothraki sea?)

Answer (score -1):

While the "bread crumb" answer is probably the correct (intended) one, in either case I think it wise to drop jewelry in case the Dothraki prefer to just cut ones finger/hand off rather than persuade one to remove it.

Answer (score -1):

Actually i think it's her engagement ring . and if you remember at Season 1 and Episode 1. Dothrakis show their liking to a girl when they circle around.

Answer (score -3):

This is read off from somewhere else.. the ring is apparently from her betrothal to Hizdahr zo Loraq. 
As widow Khaaleesi of Khal Drogo, upon his death, she was meant to become the wife/mistress of the new Khal, which was not what happened in her case. When she sees a Dothraki clan approaching, she quickly removes her engagement ring, as she fears the Dothraki Khal may get even more hostile on seeing what he might look upon as his property, wed/engaged to another.

Comment: I may have missed this in the show, but in the books this is not how it works. A widow of a Khal is taken back to Vaes Dothrak to live out her days with the other former Khaleesis, called dosh khaleen.

Comment: Agree with Dima. Don't think this is anywhere close to a correct answer. She was supposed to 'retire' with the rest of the former Khaleesis, not marry the next Khal. Anyway Nika G's answer above is the official answer from the show creators. Do you have any evidence to support this theory?

Comment: Sorry that your first question on this site didn't turn out so well. But on the plus side, deleting one of your answers with three or more downvotes gives you a badge!